Cannot understand why this code is working according to the rules of ownership
I have the following code
use euclid::Vector3D;

fn main() {
    fn add_vectors<Unit>(a: Vector3D::<f64, Unit>, b: Vector3D::<f64, Unit>) -> Vector3D::<f64, Unit> {
        // I take ownership of `a` and `b`.
        Vector3D::<f64,Unit>::new(a.x+b.x, a.y+b.y, a.z+b.z) // Explicitly create a new vector, and return it together with its ownership.
    } // `a` and `b` go out of scope, they are dropped.
    enum Meters {}
    let v1 = Vector3D::<f64,Meters>::new(1., 2., 3.);
    let v2 = Vector3D::<f64,Meters>::new(1., 2., 3.);
    // Up to here, `main` is the owner of `v1` and `v2`.
    println!("Added: {:?}", add_vectors(v1,v2)); // Ownership is transferred to `add_vectors`.
    println!("Original vectors: {:?} and {:?}", v1, v2); // `v1` and `v2` should have been dropped by now.
}

which compiles without warnings and runs, as you would expect in Python. However, this is Rust, and I don't understand how is that the second println! can use v1 and v2, given that according to my understanding from ownership (Rust book) this shouldn't be possible. Here is my reasoning:

add_vectors receives the vectors themselves, not references. Hence, it takes ownership of them.
In the body of add_vectors, a new  Vector3D::<f64,Unit> is explicitly created and returned.
When add_vectors reaches the end, a and b go out of scope, so they are dropped.
Now v1 and v2 exist no longer.

(I am just learning Rust, sorry if the answer is too obvious and I don't see it.)

euclid::Vector3D is Copy, then calling the function does not move v1 and v2 into the parameters but copies them (as if they were simple integers for example).

More precisely, it is Copy iff T is Copy: https://docs.rs/euclid/latest/src/euclid/vector.rs.html#924 which f64 is.

So this means that if T implements the Copy trait, then so it will euclid::Vector3D and it will behave the same way? Is Copy a trait or something else?

Copy is a so-called marker trait.

Copy is a marker trait which tells the compiler that the source is not invalidated by moves, and can be used after it was moved-from (in sub-structural terms, it changes a type from affine to normal)

@Masklinn that is not correct, the source cannot be used after a move. Copy tells the compiler that a type can be bit-wise copied (to another memory region).

@RichardNeumann that's just 2 sides of the same coin. A move is a bitwise copy as well (unless the compiler is able to remove it) and marks the original value as invalid.

@RichardNeumann A bitwise copy is exactly what a move does as well. As I wrote, Copy tells the compiler that the source is still valid (or if you prefer !Copy tells the compiler that the source is invalid), that's it.

You're both right. I had the misconception that a move transfers actual ownership of a memory location the stack, which is obviously not the case: https://google.github.io/comprehensive-rust/memory-management/move.html

Most of euclid's types are Copy if the underlying T is Copy. This means that they don't get moved out of their original locations, just copied.
